# Error with Uniqueidentifier deploying database to Windows Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, guid, uniqueidentifier

I am trying to test our site on the Windows Azure platform to see if it will work.  I've worked through most of the errors, but I haven't been able to get past the following.

```
Element Column: [dbo].[Subscribers].[ID] has an unsupported property IsRowGuidColumn set and is not supported when used as part of a data package.
```

I did a lot of searching and can't find anything about this particular error.  I did see some stuff about GUIDs and Azure, but nothing that's helped.

I have five tables that use a GUID/Uniqueidentifier as their primary key because they are publicly visible.

Answer (score 2):

Since RowGUID column is not supported in Windows Azure SQL Database recommended alternative is to use uniqueidentifier as the column type and then use NEWID() to generate guids at insert time.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable ( 
   MyID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWID() PRIMARY KEY, 
   Name VARCHAR(10)) 
INSERT INTO MyTable (name) VALUES ('string1') 
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (newid(), 'string2')
```

Comment: GUID isn't an actual datatype in sql server, so I do have all those columns and a uniqueidentifier.  Is it just because I don't have NEWID()?

Comment: Also, I'm trying to deploy an existing database.  How would I alter the existing tables to make this work?

Comment: I found it, it stemmed from confusion on my part with the Is GUID Column option.  I removed that and it transferred over without issue.